# I cant access my photo when making html page

Tags: html

Hello Im making a simple html website just for practice.
I uploaded a jpg image on website called 'nexus mods' and im trying to access that image with html.
I think that i'am giving wrong src address but im not sure how to fix this.
Here is link to the image on nexus https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/images/112580
and here is my html code :

```
<img src="https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/images/112580" alt="Legion boy">
```

I'am not sure how this address is wrong what i did step by step:

1- gone to the site i mentioned earlier
 2- find image i uploaded
 3- copied address from address bar and pasted it as my src

Comment: **LOOK** at the syntax highlighting to find your mistake

Comment: Response for "https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/images/112580" is not image it is a html with image inside!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote double quotes at the end of the URL. And you should right click on image and select `Copy image URL`. Here is the working code.

```
<img src="https://staticdelivery.nexusmods.com/images/130/66728631-1552854368.jpg" alt="Legion boy">
```

Comment: Thank you I feel so stupid now , i was wondering why your version of the code is so different and then it hit me to right click on the image and copy image address not the web address.